# Is socket option SO_KEEPALIVE supported for unix domain sockets (socket family AF_UNIX)?

Tags: keep-alive, unix-socket, setsockopt

In our program, communication is happening over unix domain socket. When socket is created we are enabling socket option SO_KEEPALIVE on the socket. Call to `setsockopt()` is successful but `netstats` output doesn't so it. Output is as follows.

> tcp        0      0 nemo:diamServ          nemo:15388                ESTABLISHED 19997/process_name          keepalive (7221.16/0/0)
>
> unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     228473 19997/process_name          /tmp/uds1.socket

In above output we can see that "keepalive" keyword for tcp socket but for unix socket this keyword is not there. We are not sure whether keepalive is enabled for unix socket or not?

Note that **diamServ** is the service name corresponding to the port used for tcp socket. and **/tmp/uds1.socket** is unix socket file generated.

Comment: One purpose of `SO_KEEPALIVE` is to make sure there's no problems in the network between the two peers. Since `AF_LOCAL` (a.k.a. `AF_UNIX`) sockets are all local to a single system the chances of network problems are slim to none.

Comment: That I agree. But as we have enabled `SO_KEEPALIVE`, is there a way I can check if keepalive is enabled or not on the socket? Or the `setsockopt()` call for enabling keepalive on `AF_UNIX` socket doesn't have any effect?

Comment: First of all you should check what `setsockopt` returns. Does it return with an error? If so what does e.g. `perror("setsockopet")` report? Otherwise have you checked using `getsockopt` if the option is enabled?

Comment: I don't think it returns with error as return of `setsockopt` is 0.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer too but I've found two interesting documents :

**(First)** SO_KEEPALIVE
              Enable sending of keep-alive messages on connection-oriented sockets.  Expects an integer boolean flag.
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html

**(Second)** Sockets that use the AF_UNIX or AF_UNIX_CCSID address family can be connection-oriented (type SOCK_STREAM) or connectionless (type SOCK_DGRAM).
https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzab6/uafunix.htm

It suggests that `SO_KEEPALIVE` can work on `AF_UNIX` sockets too.